# Solving a complex equation to get the minimum value.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $| z – 5 + 12 i |\le 1$ and the least and greatest values of $| z |$ are $m$ and $n$ and if $l$ be the least positive value
of
$\frac{x^2+24x+1}{x}$
  where(x > 0), then l is

(A) 2(m+ n) (B) m + n (C) m (D) n

I tried to do it by taking a circle with centre (5,-12) with radius 1 and got m and n to be 12 and 14 respectively.

Now I differentiated  $\frac{x^2+24x+1}{x}$ to get the minimum value.
So I got $1-\frac{1}{x^2}=0$.Thus getting $x=1,-1$.Since x>0 it must be 1.So by putting x=1 in the original equation I get 26 which is m+n.

I wanted to know if my process is right or not.

Comment: Both your answers (and their justifications) are correct.

Comment: @GregMartin Alright thanks.But is taking the derivative the right choice when I want to find the minimum "positive" value?

Comment: Good point. Setting the derivative equal to $0$ finds some local maximums and local minimums; but local maxs/mins can also happen at places the function is not differentiable (including where it's undefined, and endpoints of the interval of definition). Once you know all the local maxs/mins, and any asymptotic behavior, you can determine things like the global minimum, or the global minimum among all positive values, etc.

Comment: For this particular problem, you're trying to minimize $24+x+\frac1x$; since $x$ is positive, the AM-GM inequality tells us that $\frac12(x+\frac1x) \ge \sqrt{x\cdot\frac1x} = 1$, and so $x+\frac1x\ge2$; this gives the same minimum value of $26$.